# Looking for lock-free container

Tags: delphi, lock-free

I'm looking for lock-free container(List/Queue/Stack...) which can been used with delphi 2007. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)?

Comment: In my impression, it's for delphi2009-2010?

Comment: From the faq:
Is OmniThreadLibrary supported on my platform?
At the moment, OTL supports Delphi 2007, 2009, and 2010 on the Win32 platform.

Comment: what André suggested *is* the OmniThreadLibrary (yes, I know TheDelphiGeek.com is/has been temporarily down).

Answer (score 3):

google search:
http://www.google.nl/search?q=delphi+lock+free

The first search result:
http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2008/07/lock-free-queue-finally.html

Links to [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)

:-)